# angular2-meteor styleUrl doesn't load

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, angular2-meteor

I've got this component which doesn't load the style. The template loads correctly though.

```
// client/imports/navbar/navbar.ts
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: 'client/imports/navbar/navbar.html',
    styleUrls: ['client/imports/navbar/navbar.css']
})
export class Navbar {}
```

So far I've tryed:

- Setting the `base href` at the `/client/index.html`
- Injecting the `base href` at base component `/client/app.ts` in the bootstrap
- Loading the style with:

`styleUrls: [
    '/client/imports/navbar/navbar.css',
    'client/imports/navbar/navbar.css',
    'imports/navbar/navbar.css',
    './navbar.css',
    'navbar.css'
]`

However, components in the root folder load the style witthout any issue:

```
// client/app.ts
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'client/app.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.css']
})
export class AppComponent{}
```

I've already know that:

- Angular styles doesn't support relative paths
- Path should not start with slash `/`
- Paths should reffer to the root because I use SystemJs (Meteor).

But I triyed anyway.

**Update:**

The only way I find to make it moular is to declare the style inside the same template html file like this:

```
 <style>
   .my-class{
       ...
   }
 </style>
 <div class="my-class">
      ...
 </div>
```

Comment: As a workaround, you can place the CSS file in Meteor's `public/` folder. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem at the moment seems to be, that all `*.css` files are merged together by the build which is then loaded via `http://localhost:3000/merged-stylesheets.css?hash=something`, so you will get a global style with this name, but not the component-local style of Angular.

Consider the following example of mine:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'client/home.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'client/home.component.css' ]
})
export class HomeComponent extends MeteorComponent {
```

I do see an additional network request to the CSS at `client/home.component.css`, but unfortunately if you look at the content, this is treated as a "route" request and returns the entire page and not the content of the CSS.

EDIT: There seems to be already an issue filed against this: https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/270

**WORKAROUND**:

As using `styleUrls` loads the CSS on-demand, it needs to be available later. You can therefore put it in the [`public/`](http://guide.meteor.com/v1.3/structure.html#meteor-structure) folder of the meteor project. In the case of my example, the css needs to be located at `public/client/home.component.css`.